# cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:resource'

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, xml-namespaces, xml-configuration

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-mvc.xsd

    ">

    <!-- scan all the packages to identify all the controller -->

    <context:component-scan
        base-package="net.aymwus.onlineshopping.controller" />

    <!-- configure the InternalResource View Resolver -->

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="InternalResourceViewResolver">

        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>

    </bean>

    <!-- load static resource -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:resource location="/assets/" mapping="/resource/**" />


</beans>
```

when i am trying to loading the static resource and defining those

> mvc:anotation-driven

i am getting this Error.Well i want to load my static resource,but i am unable to do so.Can anyone Explain How to resolve this issues?

Comment: I doubt that `http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-mvc.xsd` is the correct namespace. `context` must probably be `mvc`.

Comment: Thanks M.Deinum.Issues got resolved.